# Component specific HostListener in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing an app in Angular 2 in which I have a parent component and child component. The child component has a HostListener of keydown event and executes some functionality. I'm able to achieve this, but the problem is if I press any key in context of the parent component then HostListener also executes. What I want is HostListener to execute if I'm in context of the child component.

This is not working as I intend to.
It is in child Component

```
@HostListener('keydown', ["$event"])
ondropdown(){ functionality }
```

This is working but on the whole page, I even tried 'window' but the effect is same.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ["$event"])
ondropdown(){ //functionality }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `in context of Parent component`?

Comment: Key listeners are generally triggered based on where the focus is. How do you determine if focus is on the host element?

Comment: Yea and in absence of any focus I feel like it would just trigger globally, virtually the same thing as a document listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a bubbling. In this case you should stop the event bubbling from the child component to the parent and prevent the default event from the parent to child .

For the child:

```
  @HostListener('keydown', ["$event"])
    ...
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

For the parent:

```
  @HostListener('keydown', ["$event"])
    ...
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```